# attach onClickListener to ToggleButton

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have a **ToggleButton** and I need to set up simple click actions. How do I implement a simple click listener for a ToggleButton?

If you need details please ask.

Comment: Show us what you have attempted so far, and explain why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

ToggleButton extends View, so you can simply use [View.setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29), like this:

```
// get your ToggleButton
ToggleButton b = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

// attach an OnClickListener
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // your click actions go here
    }
});
```

Comment: if you haven't  imported view . you can use it likeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // your click actions go here
    }
});

Answer (score 56):

```
    this.someToggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.someToggleButton) ;
    this.someToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked) {
            doSomethingWith(toggleButton, isChecked) ;
        }
    }) ;
```

Comment: I tried this first, but in my case the `OnClickListener` was actually the correct route to go, because `OnCheckedChangedListener` gets fired even when you change `isChecked` programmatically. That was causing undesired side effects when I first loaded the activity and set the initial checked state.

Comment: @jokeefe Could you not set the initial checked state before setting the `onCheckedChangedListener`?

Answer (score 33):

Use `View.setOnClickListener()` and Check state of button.

```
    final ToggleButton tB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    tB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(tB.isChecked()){
                //Button is ON
                            // Do Something 
            }
            else
            //Button is OFF
                            // Do Something     
        }
    });
```

Comment: why you have used 'final' with ToggleButton. @salman khalid
plz explain it

Comment: @LASIAF without final, inside the public void onClick() you won't be able to access tB.

Answer (score 17):

Just to add a point not emphasised in the other answers - programatically binding a click handler is a bit heavy on the bolierplate code. As mentioned in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html), it's only necessary in certain scenarios, such as:

- If the ToggleButton is instantiated at runtime
- If the click behaviour is defined in a Fragment subclass

If the ToggleButton is defined in the layout, **it's far simpler and cleaner to bind a handler method there**

```
<ToggleButton 
  android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textOn="On"
  android:textOff="Off"
  android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

Then only the handler method needs to be defined in the Activity Java

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    if(((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        // handle toggle on
    } else {
       // handle toggle off
    }    
}
```

Note  the method can have any name, but the signature must meet these criteria:

- Must be a `public` method
- Must return `void`
- Must take a single argument of type `View` (this will be the `View` which was clicked)

Comment: simple and straightforward! This should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

To add it from the code, you can do something like:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      finish();
    }
  });
```

However, you can also specify in the XML for your button, which method you want to be associated with the onClick action/event.

Answer (score 2):

```
mTB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
mTB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Is the toggle on?
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();

            if (on) {
                // Enable here
            } else {
                // Disable here
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting an answer, try to explain why this fixes this issue, along with the code.

Answer (score 1):

if above codes don't work try

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       // your click actions go here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**`setOnCheckedChangeListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) method of your [ToggleButton](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) class

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked) {
        // 
    }
}) ;
```